# How to sync pouchdb with remote Coudant, not able to connect?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, synchronization, pouchdb, cloudant

How do sync PoucDB to Cloudant by using user login? My Cloudant is set up with IAM and Legacy.

How do I  register users and use the credentials to login to use Cloudant and PouchDB

I have not found answers in Cloudant, PouchDB docs. And do not see my answer in Stackoverflow

I am using the PouchDB docs:

```
var db = new PouchDB('todos');
const remoteUrl = "https://some address"
const remoteOptions = {
   'auth': { 'username': user , 'password': pass } }  
const remoteDb = new PouchDB(remoteUrl, remoteOptions);

localDB.sync(remoteDB).on('complete', function () {
  // yay, we're in sync!
}).on('error', function (err) {
  // boo, we hit an error!
});
```

Replication does work from Cloudant to on-premise Couchdb. Therefore I can connect to Coudant remotely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting error using bearer authorization to sync PouchDB to Cloudant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344357/getting-error-using-bearer-authorization-to-sync-pouchdb-to-cloudant)

Comment: Thanks, it helps, but where do I find my token?

Comment: See https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/iam-identity-token-api#authentication

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the right way to have users get access to cloudant. Can I use user login with cloudant credentials or database users?

Comment: Someone else needs to weigh in my expertise with Cloudant is cursory, good luck. If you find the solution, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have Legacy Auth available, I won't worry about IAM authentication. We can simply generate an API key/password for your mobile client and use legacy authentication.

**Creating an API key**

In the Cloudant Dashboard, choose the "Permissions" menu and click the "Generate API Key" button. You should see a generated Key and Password - these become the Username & Password in the URL you feed to PouchDB.

If you're doing a sync (i.e data is to flow in both directions) then your API key needs both `_reader` & `_writer` permissions. If data is to flow from server to mobile only, then `_reader` & `_replicator` will suffice.

**Client-side code**

Your client side code is pretty much correct:

- remember that Cloudant only accepts HTTPS connections
- the Key from your API Key/Password pair becomes your username
- the Password from your API Key/Password pair becomes your password

e.g.

```js
const PouchDB = require('pouchdb')
const db = new PouchDB('todos')
const username = 'KEY'
const password = 'PASSWORD'
const host = 'mycloudservice.cloudant.com'
const databaseName = 'todos'
const remoteDB = `https://${username}:${password}@${host}/${databaseName}`
    
db.sync(remoteDB).on('complete', async function () { 
 console.log('done')
}).on('error', function (err) {
  console.error(err)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. How would a user login? Do i need to make a api key for each? Also how is the API key and password hidden for security?

Comment: @MorganHayes you would have to have a server-side service that handled authentication and dished out Cloudant API keys to authorised users.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, started working on it yesterday. It is slow going. Do you know any examples or advice.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: @GlennBird I have built an API to handle authentication and to dish out Cloudant API Key. I have not been able to find code examples of how to implement the dishing out of the key part. Do you know of any?